# Is there any way to auto generate POJO in springboot project

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite (STS). I am confused is there any way to autogenerate POJO based on table in postgres sql along with mapping.

I know how to generate POJO from database table in Advanced Java project on eclipse but I tried for spring project in STS with no positive result.

In advanced Java project I simply use this link http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm

It would be helpful if anyone share their thoughts.